# AWS CloudFormation YAML !Or function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Error: "Template validation error: Template format error: Conditions can only be boolean operations on parameters and other conditions"

Working JSON conditions block:

```
"Conditions" : {
    "CreateBetaResources" : {"Fn::Or" : [ {"Fn::Equals" : [{"Ref" : "Environment"}, "beta"]}, {"Fn::Equals" : [{"Ref" : "Environment"}, "eubeta"]} ]},
    "CreateStagingResources" : {"Fn::Equals" : [{"Ref" : "Environment"}, "staging"]},
    "CreateProdResources" : { "Fn::Or": [ {"Fn::Equals" : [{"Ref" : "Environment"}, "prod"]}, {"Fn::Equals" : [{"Ref" : "Environment"}, "euprod"]} ] }
  },
```

YAML block which isn't working:

```
Conditions:
  CreateBetaResources:
    !Or [!Equals [!Ref "Environment", beta], !Equals [!Ref "Environment", eubeta]]
  CreateStagingResources:
    - !Equals [!Ref "Environment", staging]
  CreateProdResources:
    !Or [!Equals [!Ref "Environment", prod], !Equals [!Ref "Environment", euprod]]
```

Why is this error happening? I've scoured the documentation on "Fn::Or" and conditionals... It seems as though the syntax is correct. I've also tried many, many other formats, but this is the one closest to the documentation example.

Comment: Could you also put down the code where you are using this condition and the "Environment" parameter definition?

Comment: I actually just figured out what is going on. You can't have type list for Condition statements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The proper way to instantiate !Or/!Equals inside a condition block with YAML is as follows:

```
Conditions:
 CreateBetaResources: !Or [!Equals [!Ref "Environment", beta], !Equals [!Ref "Environment", eubeta]]
 CreateStagingResources: !Equals [!Ref "Environment", staging]
 CreateProdResources: !Or [!Equals [!Ref "Environment", prod], !Equals [!Ref "Environment", euprod]]
```

Do not include the list identifier before calling the !Equals function (-).